# How can I solve the directory problem of cplex in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cplex

[enter image description here][1]I'm developing a c++ code on eclipse and i need cplex.

```
#include "ilcplex/ilocplex.h".
```

I have made this passages:

```
- project\properties\C/C++ built\Settings\GCC C++ compiler\Includes:
"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio126\cplex\include"
-project\properties\C/C++ built\Settings\MinGW C++ Linker\libraries:
"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio126\cplex\include\ilcplex"
```

and the library seems to be ok, since if i use f3 it works.

Despite this, it continues to give me this message:
fatal error: ilcplex/ilocplex.h no such file or directory.
I have tried to follow the instructions of the other similar posts, but nothing changed.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you setup your include path for `ilcplex`? This means when searching the include paths it could not find a directory listed in the paths containing a subfolder `ilcplex` which had a file named  `ilocplex.h`

Comment: _@NataliaSacco_ You should give us more information about your source code, and specific project settings please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes sorry

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio126\cplex\include` contain a `ilcplex` folder?

Comment: @drescherjm yes, and i can't understand why there is this error

Comment: I don't think `"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio126\cplex\include\ilcplex"` is correct for the linker path. But that has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: `#include "ilcplex/ilocplex.h".` I assume you don't have the `.` at the end in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you fix the error you are getting now, using CPLEX with `gcc` on Windows is not something that is supported, and it's likely you'll just run into another error. If you look at the [detailed system requirements](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100) for CPLEX on Windows, you will see that Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017 is required. You should take a look at the `c_cpp.html` file that gets installed with CPLEX for instructions on how to set up the Visual Studio environment when working with C/C++ projects.

Comment: thank you! At the end I installed Visual Studio, and it worked without problem!

Comment: @NataliaSacco: glad to help. If you don't mind, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others can see that the question has been resolved.